# As I run the Cellranger count, I get the following error: "The argument '--fastqs <PATH>...' requires a value but none was supplied"

Tags: linux, bioinformatics, sequencing

I am following the 10x Cellranger steps and using the same files for cellranger count. I run this from the fastq directory that contains all the PBMCs fastq files and the GRCh38 files too.

[image]

Comment: [Why not upload code/text images in Questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Answer (score 0):

You put a space between `--fastqs=` and `/home/.../pbmc_1k_v3_fastqs`, and thus it think you didn't provide an argument after `--fastqs`. There are two possible syntax:

- either you want a space, but then don't put a `=`, as in `--fastqs /home/.../pbmc_1k_v3_fastqs`;
- or you put an equal sign, but then don't put a space, as in `--fastqs=/home/.../pbmc_1k_v3_fastqs`.